# How to make JS async function run in sync with others?

Tags: javascript, async-await

The following JS code:

```
function promise_GetSomething() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("Something gotten after 3 sec.");
        }, 3000);
    });
}

async function logAboutSomethingGotten() {
    console.log("Before getting 3-sec-something.");
    var somethingGotten = await promise_GetSomething();
    console.log(somethingGotten);
    console.log("After getting 3-sec-something.");
}

function doSomething() {
    console.log("START");
    logAboutSomethingGotten();
    console.log("STOP");
}

doSomething();
```

...prints the following:

```
START
Before getting 3-sec-something.
STOP
Something gotten after 3 sec.
After getting 3-sec-something.
```

How can I adjust it to print the following?

```
START
Before getting 3-sec-something.
Something gotten after 3 sec.
After getting 3-sec-something.
STOP
```

Also, if the async `logAboutSomethingGotten()` returns a value, how can the value be gotten and used synchronously?

**EDIT (UTC 2019-01-12 11:14 PM):**

Thanks to the current answerers. The current answers all mostly suggest making `doSomething()` async and await `logAboutSomethingGotten()`. I had known this too, but because it could lead to maybe an endless async-await code, I didn't like that solution. Also, the option involving piping a `.then(function() { console.log("STOP"); })` unto `logAboutSomethingGotten()` too would easily somehow solve that but not in all scenarios, like for the synchronous part of my question.

**So, I'm particularly interested in if `logAboutSomethingGotten()` returns a value (e.g. after making an Ajax call, because synchronous Ajax is being deprecated).** By what clever means can I use this returned value in a synchronous flow?

Answer (score 1):

Do this->

```
async function doSomething() {
    console.log("START");
    await logAboutSomethingGotten();
    console.log("STOP");

}
```

Check the snip-

```js
function promise_GetSomething() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("Something gotten after 3 sec.");
        }, 3000);
    });
}

async function logAboutSomethingGotten() {
    console.log("Before getting 3-sec-something.");
    var somethingGotten = await promise_GetSomething();
    console.log(somethingGotten);
    console.log("After getting 3-sec-something.");
}

async function doSomething() {
    console.log("START");
    await logAboutSomethingGotten();
    console.log("STOP");
    
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just mark `doSomething` as `async` and then `await` the `logAboutSomethingGotten();` call.

> If the async `logAboutSomethingGotten()` returns a value, how can the value be gotten and used synchronously?

An asynchronous result can never be used synchronously. Of course, after waiting for the promise you can always use the return value as normal.

Comment: I am particularly interested in using the asynchronous result in a synchronous way. I actually figured out I could keep adding "async" and "await" quite endlessly. Can you please provide a workaround?

Comment: @Olumide No. When I wrote *never*, I meant that it is impossible. You have to add `async` and `await` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `doSomething` function to also be asynchronous, and await `logAboutSomethingGotten`.

```
function promise_GetSomething() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("Something gotten after 3 sec.");
        }, 3000);
    });
}

async function logAboutSomethingGotten() {
    console.log("Before getting 3-sec-something.");
    var somethingGotten = await promise_GetSomething();
    console.log(somethingGotten);
    console.log("After getting 3-sec-something.");
}

async function doSomething() {
    console.log("START");
    await logAboutSomethingGotten();
    console.log("STOP");
}

doSomething();
```